# Pandas + scikit-learn K-means not working properly - treats all of dataframe rows as one big multi-dimensional example

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am currently trying to do some k-means clustering using my data which is stored in my pandas.dataframe (actually in one of its columns). Odd thing is that instead of treating each row as a separate example it threats all rows as one example but in very high dimension. So for example:

```
df = pd.read_csv('D:\\Apps\\DataSciense\\Kaggle Challenges\\Titanic\\Source Data\\train.csv', header = 0)

median_ages = np.zeros((2,3))

for i in range(0,2):
    for j in range (0,3):
        median_ages[i, j] =df[(df.Gender == i) &(df.Pclass == j+1)].Age.dropna().median()

df['AgeFill'] = df['Age']

for i in range(0, 2):
    for j in range(0,3):
        df.loc[ (df.Age.isnull()) & (df.Gender == i) & (df.Pclass == j+1), 'AgeFill'] = median_ages[i, j]
```

then I just check that it looks fine:

```
df.AgeFill

Name: AgeFill, Length: 891, dtype: float64
```

Looks ok, 891 float64 number. I do custering:

```
k_means = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=1, init='random')
k_means.fit(df.AgeFill)
```

And I check for cluster centers:

```
k_means.cluster_centers_
```

It returns me one giant array.

Furthermore:

```
k_means.labels_
```

Gives me:

```
array([0])
```

What am I doing wrong? Why it thinks I have a one example with 891 dimensions, instead of having 891 example?

Just to illustrate it better, if I try 2 clusters:

```
k_means = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=2, init='random')
k_means.fit(df.AgeFill)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    k_means.fit(df.AgeFill)
  File "D:\Apps\Python\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\k_means_.py", line 724, in fit
    X = self._check_fit_data(X)
  File "D:\Apps\Python\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\k_means_.py", line 693, in _check_fit_data
    X.shape[0], self.n_clusters))
ValueError: n_samples=1 should be >= n_clusters=2

So you could see that it REALLY thinks that it is just one giant sample.

But:

```
df.AgeFill.shape
(891,)
```

Comment: Try `k_means.fit(df['AgeFill'].values)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are passing a 1D array while scikit expects a 2D array with a **samples** and a **features** axis. This should do it:

```
k_means.fit(df.AgeFill.reshape(-1, 1))
```

Before:

```
>>> df.AgeFill.shape
(891,)
```

After:

```
>>> df.AgeFill.reshape(-1, 1).shape
(891, 1)
```

Comment: Just one last question, what is the 'features' which it expects in axis?

Comment: In your example you used only 1 feature(`AgeFill`) but you could have used more than one, for example: `df[['AgeFill', 'Gender']]`. In this case it is already 2D (`shape = (891,2)`) so you don't need to reshape. The features axis would be the columns of your Dataframe.